# CActiveDataProvider выборка c alias

Tags: php, yii, mysql

Добрый день! Начал изучать yii. Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Делаю пример блога по руководству с офф. сайта и стало интересно, как с помощью данного класса выполнить запрос, в котором будет добавлен алиас. Например, выполняется запрос

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_post`
```

А вот если нужен

```
SELECT * , `author_id` AS 'user' FROM `tbl_post`
```

то что надо написать в параметры? По умолчанию все выглядит вот так:

```
$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Post');
```

В Google искал, но так и не нашел подобного примера, возможно плохо искал, подскажите, кто знает, плз)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сделать вот так:

```
$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Post',
                  array (
                         'criteria'=>array(
                                      'select'=>'* , `author_id` AS `user` ',
                                          ),
                         ));
```

Но для того чтоб это заработало необходимо в модели Post добавить  артибут   user, т.е

```
class Post extends CActiveRecord
 {
     public $user;
 // далее ваш код

//Также атрибут необходимо зделать несохраняемым в базу
  public function rules() 
        {
        //ваш код

        array ( 'user',
                'unSafe'
              )
        }
 }
```

Сам недавно начал изучать этот фрэймворк (первый который изучаю)  пока нравится

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. Попробую, если сработает отмечу как правильный. а пока ловите плюс)